# Error...number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, matrix, numeric, equation, populate

```
S = 0.001 # slope
h = 0.7 # m depth of flow
v = 0.000001 # m^2/s dynamic viscosity of water
g = 9.8 # m/s^2 gravitational acceleration

velocity <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 14)

velocity[1,2] <- 0.05
velocity[2,2] <- 0.1
velocity[3,2] <- 0.15
velocity[4,2] <- 0.2
velocity[5,2] <- 0.25
velocity[6,2] <- 0.3
velocity[7,2] <- 0.35
velocity[8,2] <- 0.4
velocity[9,2] <- 0.45
velocity[10,2] <- 0.5
velocity[11,2] <- 0.55
velocity[12,2] <- 0.6
velocity[13,2] <- 0.65
velocity[14,2] <- 0.7

for(i in 1:14){
  velocity[i,] <- (sqrt(g*h*S)/k) * log(velocity[,i]/z0)
}

print(velocity)
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I have a matrix with 14 rows and am trying to use the 2nd column to calculate the first column with the included equation. Changing the loop to `for(i in 1:n)` gives a NA error

Comment: 0.4 and 0.002. I should have included them but they are defined elsewhere and are not causing the issue (I made sure by adding them to this particular cell).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get values for col1 by col2, what about trying this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(velocity)){
  velocity[i,1] <- (sqrt(g*h*S)/k) * log(velocity[i,2]/z0)
}
```

Without loops, you can also try this:

```
velocity[,1] = (sqrt(g*h*S)/k) * log(velocity[,2]/z0)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Trying to adjust to r from a very limited knowledge of python.

Comment: The same, I have also recently been trying to work with R and Python at the same time. Good luck!